Flutter Web memory leak
We use Flutter web, which allows users to collect data. Lately we've been having performance problems, with the app becoming slower and slower after using it for a long time, until it's almost impossible to use it anymore. Reloading the application solves the problem. But that's not a real "solution" since our app is also used offline.
I have already tried the following things:

First I tried to find out if it was due to a certain part of the application, but no matter which part of the application you use the application becomes slower.
I then checked whether all resources were released in the dispose-method.
Unfortunately, debugging with Flutter dev tools cannot be used with Flutter Web and reading the cache in the Chrome browser is rather difficult because the cache is not really readable.

And then I noticed that the application's cache was growing extremely quickly. After 15 minutes of using the application, the cache has already grown by 161%.
But if I build our Flutter project as an APK and use it for 15 minutes, there is no memory leak. Memory only grew by 19%, which looks normal to me. If I build the application in release mode, it is 30MB in size and I can easily handle a 19% memory increase.
If necessary, we could also imagine changing technology from Flutter Web to Android / IOS app, but there must be a problem that Flutter Web allocates memory so quickly and doesn't release it again.
I'm grateful for any help :)
Here are some details to our project:
web memory
apk memory
<html>
<head>
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
  <script src="pdfjs/pdf.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  <script src="pdfjs/pdf.worker.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  <script src="indexResources/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript" defer></script>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="project">


  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/project-Icon-192.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexResources/index.css">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <title>project</title>
</head>
<body>
  <picture id="splash">
      <source srcset="splash/img/light-1x.png 1x, splash/img/light-2x.png 2x, splash/img/light-3x.png 3x, splash/img/light-4x.png 4x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
      <source srcset="splash/img/dark-1x.png 1x, splash/img/dark-2x.png 2x, splash/img/dark-3x.png 3x, splash/img/dark-4x.png 4x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
      <img class="center" aria-hidden="true" src="splash/img/light-1x.png" alt="">
  </picture>
</body>
</html>

index.html
name: project
description: A new Flutter project.

# Prevent accidental publishing to pub.dev.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.9-SNAPSHOT

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.19.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.1
  connectivity_plus: ^6.0.3
  salomon_bottom_bar: ^3.3.2
  validators: ^3.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.2
  url_launcher: ^6.2.6
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  csv: ^6.0.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.7.1
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  flutter_animate: ^4.2.0+1
  logging: ^1.2.0
  animations: ^2.0.8
  package_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.1.0
  device_info_plus: ^10.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.1.5

dev_dependencies:
  mockito: ^5.3.2
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.10
  hive_generator: ^2.0.1
  freezed: 2.5.2
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true

  assets:
    # Add assets from the images directory to the application.
    - assets/images/
    - assets/pdf/
    - assets/images/_common/
    - assets/mock/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/info.md
    - assets/mock/data.json

  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf

pubspec.yaml
